# auto minimize window with javascript - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, autoresize

I try to auto minimize window when I click a link. I don't want when I click to open on a new tab, but in a new which minimize automatically. I searched the answers but I the only answer that I found was that it's not possible, but an example of what I want you can find at  http://www.medifastcouponsfor2010.org/ when you click the red button.
So what do you suggest?

Comment: Why do you want to do such things?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The site you linked also doesn't minimize here (Chrome 9)...what you want isn't allowed, at least not across all browsers...and hopefully for obvious reasons.

This would be an advertisers dream, crank the volume, minimize the window and force you to listen to their ad while you had to hunt down the window.

Doing this would only make me want to physically harm you as quick as possible, please don't even *try* to do this.

Comment: thanks for your fast answer. Is it possible to open in a new window, not tab, with specific size?

Comment: @Sotiris - you can use [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) with dimensions, but the browser doesn't *have* to respect that, it can just open the window in a new tab if it wants...newer browsers tend to do this by default.